# PHP - how to assure correct command execution sequence

Tags: php, command, delayed-execution

Given a simple code like :

```
$file = 'hugefile.jpg';
$bckp_file = 'hugeimage-backup.jpg';
// here comes some manipulation on $bckp_file.
```

The assumed problem is  that if the file is big or huge - let´s say a jpg - One would think that it will take the server some time to copy it (by time I mean even a few milliseconds) - but one would also assume that the execution of the next line would be much faster ..
So in theory - I could end up with "no such file or directory" error when trying to manipulate file that has not yet created - or worse - start to manipulate a *TRUNCATED* file.

My question is how can I assure that $bckp_file was created (or in this case -copied) successfully before the NEXT line  which manipulates it .

What are my options to "pause" , "delay"  the next line execution until the file creation / copy was completed ?

right now  I can only think of something like

```
if (!copy($file, $bckp_file)) {
    echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
}
```

which will only alert me but will not resolve anything (same like having the php error)

or

```
if (copy($file, $bckp_file)) {
  // move the manipulation to here ..
}
```

But this is also not so valid - because let´s say the copy was not executed - I will just go out of the loop without achieving my goal and without errors.

Is that even a problem or am I over-thinking it ? 
Or is PHP has a bulit-in mechanism to ensure that ?
Any recommended practices ? 
any thoughts on the issue ? ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are my options to "pause" , "delay" the next line execution until the file is creation / copy was completes

copy() is a synchronous function meaning that code will not continue after the call to copy() until copy() either completely finishes or fails.

In other words, there's no magic involved.

```
if (copy(...)) { echo 'success!'; } else { echo 'failure!'; }
```

Along with synchronous IO, there is also asynchronous IO.  It's a bit complicated to explain in technical detail, but the general idea of it is that it runs in the background and your code hooks into it.  Then, whenever a significant event happens, the background execution alerts your code.  For example, if you were going to async copy a file, you would register a listener to the copying that would be notified when progress was made.  That way, your code could do other things in the mean time, but you could also know what progress was being made on the file.

Comment: thanks for the answer . nothing is out of the scope of the question - because I am trying to learn more and understand more :-) . one other issue that was mentioned in the question - what in the case of TRUNCATED file ? does the php-synchronous-mechanisem checks also integrity ? because again  in theory - a .jpg file can be created and saved / copied but contain false information (we all saw half-greyed jpg´s from the net..)

Comment: Have updated my answer to include a bit of info on async IO :)

Answer (score 1):

PHP handles file uploads by saving the whole file in a temporary directory on the server before executing any of script (so you can use $_FILES from the beginning), and it's safe to assume all functions are synchronous -- that is, PHP will wait for each line to execute before moving to the next line.

Comment: but "execute" is not always a synonymous to "successfully execute" - unless  like you said I can assume that PHP takes care of that under all circumstances ..

Comment: Could be wrong on this, but I do not believe copy() creates a temporary copy of the file while copying.  Perhaps you are assuming that the question asker was talking about uploaded files?  If so, move_uploaded_file should probably be used instead, and I do not believe that's what she was talking about.

Comment: Yes I made the assumption it was related to file uploads and `move_uploaded_file`, but it applies to the `copy()` function too (see http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php). Both functions return the status of the copy operation, which it would not be able to return until the copy is complete (either successful or failed). They are therefore synchronous.

Comment: Of course they're synchronous.  My point is that copy() does not create a temporary file when copying.  Why would it?  It would then have to copy twice.  (move_upload_file does involve a temporary file, but that's unrelated to copy())

Comment: Edited answer to clarify that I'm talking about file uploads. Either way the temp file discussion is irrelevant, standard file operations are synchronous and you will always deal with the result of the operation after the operation executes.